# How do I move/select menu options through UI joystick and buttons?

Tags: unity, gui, menu

I have a working Menu system in my game. I am able to move across the menu using <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys and select those options using the enter key. The problem is how do i get that arrow key functionality to a UI joystick and enter key functionality to a UI button that I have.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance. Let me know if you need any more details, happy to provide videos of the problem, code, or the entire project if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by hard rigging it.

I used the joystick input -> up/down/left/right input sets the button (`GameObject`) in that direction as the current selected in the `EventSystem`.

For button click and invoking that button's functionality I used `ExecuteEvents.Execute()`.

Comment: If this fixed your issue, you might want to mark the answer as accepted :)